# Keycloak FTL: How to access template variable that a session has ended or a user logged out within login template on a custom theme

Tags: notifications, keycloak, freemarker, keycloak-services, custom-theme

I'm using Keycloak as an authentication for a React app and customizing the login page by modifying the `login.ftl` file. I'm importing the `template.ftl` file in my `login.ftl`, according to Keycloak's docs, and everything works fine. Inside the template.ftl file, I can access template variables like so,

```xml
<#if displayMessage && message?has_content && (message.type != 'warning' || !isAppInitiatedAction??)>
          <div class="alert alert-${message.type}">
              <#if message.type = 'success'><span class="${properties.kcFeedbackSuccessIcon!}"></span></#if>
              <#if message.type = 'warning'><span class="${properties.kcFeedbackWarningIcon!}"></span></#if>
              <#if message.type = 'error'><span class="${properties.kcFeedbackErrorIcon!}"></span></#if>
              <#if message.type = 'info'><span class="${properties.kcFeedbackInfoIcon!}"></span></#if>
              <span class="kc-feedback-text">${kcSanitize(message.summary)?no_esc}</span>
          </div>
      </#if>
```

With that in mind, is there a way to access a template variable in the `template.ftl` or `login.ftl` file that will give information that a session has just ended or a user was redirected to the login page because they just logged out? When a user gets redirected to the login page after logging out, I want to display a message UI either in the `template.ftl` or `login.ftl` that a user has just logged out.